# How to set a html page in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-views, django-urls

I started to follow this [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/python-from-scratch-create-a-dynamic-website--net-22787) and it teaches how to load the `index.html`, but now I need to develop a `login.html` page, but it seems not be working properly.

[image]

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'provisioning.views.home', name='home'), <- it works!
    url(r'^$', 'provisioning.views.login', name='login'), <- doesn't work..

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

views.py

```
def login(request):
    return render(request, 'login.html')
```

How to setup the pages to be loaded by django ? 
Is there another and better way in doing this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the same URLs for both home and login. The regex pattern r'^$' specifies that  nothing comes after your local host. Because they are the same and Django checks URLs sequentially, only the first url and view is called. Try adding a different url for login.

`url(r'^login/$', 'provisioning.views.login', name='login')`

Comment: It worked! Thank you sir! Another mistake of mine, I was trying to use `http://localhost:8000/login.html` insted of `http://localhost:8000/login/` which is the correct.

Comment: do you mind accepting my answer? It's really annoying not being able to comment on posts until I have 50 rep.

Comment: Oh sure, I had to wait for some time before to be able to accept your answer. Thank you once more.